# How can I make code more beautiful?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Could you give me a hint on how I can make following code more shortly and beautiful:

```
Persons.with_tour.map(&:father).map(&:first_name).to_sentence
```

Comment: you may also wana check this https://github.com/styleguide/ruby

Comment: By the way: while your question is perfectly on-topic here on StackOverflow, it is *also* on-topic on the [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), where it might get better answers than here. However, please don't cross-post. If you wish your question to appear there, you should ask a moderator on that site, or flag your question for moderator attention on this site and ask for it to be migrated.

Comment: @JörgWMittag While it might be debatable whether this is on-topic or off-topic on Code Review, chances are it would be closed for stub code, or hypothetical code.

Comment: @EthanBierlein: Yes, sorry, I should have mentioned that. I wanted to add something to the effect that the question would need some additional work done to be accepted there (and really, to be fair, here, too), but I a) got distracted and b) assumed (perhaps wrongly) that the OP would always read the help center of any site before posting there.

Comment: You can take a look at this for [a great example of how to ask a CR question about a single line of code](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/104020/41243).

Comment: Why does this question have so many downvotes?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I have your models right, but here is the idea.  Instead of selecting persons and looping through to get fathers, select fathers from the beginning, filter however you need.  And, if you're not going to user the entire father object (you just want the first names), use pluck instead to get the array.

```
Father.of_tour_persons.pluck(:first_name).to_sentence
```

and in father.rb

```
class Father < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :of_tour_persons, -> { joins(:persons).where(:persons => { :with_tour => true }) }

end
```

Comment: thank great! I didn't go deep inside this model too. But I'm sure it will help me in future! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Persons.with_tour.collect{|x| [x.father, x.first_name]}.to_sentence
```

Comment: Are you sure that does the same thing? Does `to_sentence` even know what to do with an array-of-arrays?

Comment: Dawn Green, thank you much! Didn't know about that)